# Best way to import from HDD to networked drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

How would I transfer all contents out of the HDD onto the networked drive? I don't want to plug the HDD directly into the networked drive.

Comment: How does this relate to... Wait... What in the hells is going on in this Feed the Beast pack?? O_o

Comment: @OrcJMR Join us...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this without connecting the storage cell directly to the network is to attach an [ME IO Port](http://ftbwiki.org/ME_IO_Port), which will transfer any items on storage cells inserted into it directly into the ME network, and then spit out the empty storage cell.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it in the ME IO Port will empty it out and sort it (If you formatted you Storage Drives.) If your storage system runs out of space the drive will wait for more space. Then the drive will appear on the other side of the ME IO available for you to take out when needed.